# Excel: Referencing a cell from another workbook using a dynamic filepath/filename, inside a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 50 students, each with a gradebook with many scores I am compiling in a master tracker workbook. The data points come from about 60 different worksheets within each student workbook. Rather than have a unique formula for every students' row, I want to use dynamic filepaths/filenames.

This is simplified version of the current set up.

STU_01 - Gradebook.xlsx:

Tab1!A1: 3.35

Workbook 2.xlsx:

A1: 01

B1:

```
    =IFERROR('C:\Grades\STU_01\[STU_01 - Gradebook.xlsx]Tab1'!$A$1,"")
```

This correct outputs as "3.35"

Now as I create dynamic filepaths I came up with this:

```
    ="C:\Grades\STU_" & A1 & "\[STU_" & A1 & " - Gradebook.xlsx]
```

correctly displays as

```
    C:\Grades\STU_01\[STU_01 - Gradebook.xlsx]
```

Question 1: What needs to be done to call for the value of Tab1!$A$1 while maintaining the dynamic filepath/filename?

Question 2: Can the answer to Question 1 be used in a formula, like the IFERROR() I am already using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Take a look at the INDIRECT function. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261

Comment: I have done what you're describing using INDIRECT, as @FlexYourData suggested.

Comment: Note you may have to have the other workbooks to be open to use indirect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/referencing-value-in-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-indirect

Comment: I have some experience using INDIRECT functions to call on values from other cells in open workbooks, but was hoping there was a method of avoiding INDIRECTs for these so I could access closed workbooks. Using INDIRECT functions would require me to open 51 workbooks simultaneously to keep the calls correct.

Comment: I'm also open to the idea that what I'm looking to do cannot be done using Excel. I have no background in any of this, but my Google research indicates I might be better off learning to use Access or a combination of Access/SQL since I also need multi-user ability

Comment: Care to write code in Python? "Pandas" is a package that can be added and provides ways to read excel files and do similar things as Excel (e.g. Pivot tables). In my opinion that would be a smarter way to work with numerous files.

Comment: @Hannu I don't have any background in coding whatsoever. If my requirements are beyond the limitations of Excel I will likely just outsource the project to someone who is trained. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Python has at least two or three very big advantages; 1. It is easy to learn, 2. very many people use Python 3. as a result of 2; there are a huge number of examples on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA to compose a text of your formula and then assign it to the `.Formula` property of the cell. Something like this:

```
Sub ActiveFormula()
   Dim tf As String, cel As Range, id As Range
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Set id = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
   On Error Resume Next
   For Each cel In id
      tf = Range("B1").Value & Range("A" & cel.Row).Value & _
      Range("C1").Value & Range("A" & cel.Row).Value & Range("D1").Value
      Range("F" & cel.Row).Formula = tf
   Next cel
   On Error GoTo 0
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Here parts of the formula are placed in cells (the first row), however the constant parts may be defined as constants in the code. The results should be in column `F`, assuming the source files exist.
[image: Formula From Text]